# How to get name of directory having audio files using mediastore.audio in android

Tags: android, audio, video, audio-player

I'm working on audio and video player. I got all video's folder name using `mediastore.video.media.bucket_display_name`, it's working perfectly with video files but when i uses `mediastore.audio.media.bucket_display_name` it shows error. Can anybody help me to get name of folders containing audio files. I need to do this using cursor. And i got this error:

```
 "no such column: bucket_display_name (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT bucket_display_name FROM audio"
```

Comment: Use `MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM` instead for Audio.

Comment: can you elaborate. How i use this? You mean instead of getting folder name, i get album name?

Comment: Thanks it work for me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get folders name:

```
fun getFolderName() {
                
                val uri: Uri
                val cursor: Cursor?
        
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA)
                cursor = requireActivity().contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
                if (cursor != null) {
                    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA)
                }
                
                while (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
        
                    absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data)
        
        
                    val fileName: String = File(absolutePathOfImage).parentFile.name
        }
    }
```