# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: bucket_display_name

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, mediastore, sqliteexception

I was trying to get buckets having audio files using `MediaStore`. This is working fine on Android 10 API 29 but not working previous Android versions. I've attached a screenshot of working example on Android 10 API 29.

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:
>   bucket_display_name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT
>   bucket_display_name, bucket_id FROM audio ORDER BY date_added ASC

[image: Android 10 Q API 29]

logcat.

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: bucket_display_name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT bucket_display_name, bucket_id FROM audio ORDER BY date_added ASC
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:802)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:752)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:710)
        at com.aisar.mediaplayer.fragments.AudioFolderFragment$AsyncVideoFolderLoader.doInBackground(AudioFolderFragment.java:148)
        at com.aisar.mediaplayer.fragments.AudioFolderFragment$AsyncVideoFolderLoader.doInBackground(AudioFolderFragment.java:130)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Code:

```
class AsyncVideoFolderLoader extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<ModelAudioFolder>> {

    private String sortBy;

    public AsyncVideoFolderLoader(String sortBy) {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ModelAudioFolder> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        List<ModelAudioFolder> videoItems = new ArrayList<>();
        videoItems.clear();

        final HashMap<String, ModelAudioFolder> output = new HashMap<>();
        final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        final String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_ID};

        try (final Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                contentUri,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                "" + sortBy)) {
            if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToFirst())) {
                final int columnBucketName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int columnBucketId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_ID);


                do {
                    final String bucketName = cursor.getString(columnBucketName);
                    final String bucketId = cursor.getString(columnBucketId);

                    if (!output.containsKey(bucketId)) {
                        final int count = getCount(contentUri, bucketId);

                        final ModelAudioFolder item = new ModelAudioFolder(
                                "" + bucketId,
                                "" + bucketName,
                                "",
                                "" + getPath(bucketId),
                                "" + count
                        );

                        output.put(bucketId, item);
                        videoItems.add(item);

                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return videoItems;
    }

    private int getCount(@NonNull final Uri contentUri, @NonNull final String bucketId) {
        try (final Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_ID + "=?", new String[]{bucketId}, null)) {
            return ((cursor == null) || (cursor.moveToFirst() == false)) ? 0 : cursor.getCount();
        }
    }

    private String getPath(String BUCKET_ID) {
        String path = "";
        String selection = null;
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_ID
        };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                null,
                null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (BUCKET_ID.equals(cursor.getString(1))) {
                //add only those videos that are in selected/chosen folder
                path = cursor.getString(0);
            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ModelAudioFolder> audioFolderList) {
        super.onPostExecute(audioFolderList);

        if (audioFolderList.size() <= 0) {
            noFoldersRl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            foldersRl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            noFoldersRl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            foldersRl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        Log.d("FoldersSize", "onPostExecute: " + audioFolderList.size());

        adapterAudioFolder = new AdapterAudioFolder(getActivity(), audioFolderList, dashboardActivity);
        foldersRv.setAdapter(adapterAudioFolder);
    }
}
```

...

Comment: post the code of creation/structure of table 'audio'

Comment: that's the complete class to load Audio Buckets using 'MediaStore' class. If I'm still understanding wrong let me know

Comment: I can get the folders name. I posted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63521994/5328951)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it my self now. First retrieved all audio files, then separated audio URIs. From audio URIs, I've got Folder Names. I'm posting my solution here so maybe someone else can get benefit from it.

```
class AsyncVideoFolderLoader extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<ModelAudioFolder>> {

    private Cursor cursor;
    List<ModelAudioTe> audioList;

    private String sortBy;

    public AsyncVideoFolderLoader(String sortBy) {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ModelAudioFolder> doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String selection = null;
        String[] projection;
        projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
        };
        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                null,
                null);
        audioList = new ArrayList<>();
        ModelAudioTe modelAudio;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


            modelAudio = new ModelAudioTe(
                    "" + cursor.getString(0),
                    "" + cursor.getString(1),
                    "" + cursor.getString(2),
                    "" + cursor.getString(3),
                    "" + cursor.getString(4),
                    "" + cursor.getString(5),
                    "" + cursor.getString(6),
                    "" + cursor.getString(7));
            audioList.add(modelAudio);

        }


        //creating audio paths/uris list
        ArrayList<String> pathsList = new ArrayList<>();
        pathsList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < audioList.size(); i++) {
            String folderName = new File(audioList.get(i).getDATA()).getParentFile().getName();
            String folderId = new File(audioList.get(i).getDATA()).getParentFile().getParent();
            pathsList.add(folderId + "/" + folderName);
        }


        //generating folder names from audio paths/uris
        List<ModelAudioFolder> folderList = new ArrayList<>();
        folderList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < audioList.size(); i++) {

            String folderName = new File(audioList.get(i).getDATA()).getParentFile().getName();
            String folderId = new File(audioList.get(i).getDATA()).getParentFile().getParent();
            int count = Collections.frequency(pathsList, folderId + "/" + folderName);

            String folderRoot;
            String folderRoot1 = "";
            if (audioList.get(i).getDATA().contains("emulated")) {
                folderRoot = "emulated";
            } else {
                folderRoot = "storage";
            }

            if (i > 0) {
                if (audioList.get(i - 1).getDATA().contains("emulated")) {
                    folderRoot1 = "emulated";
                } else {
                    folderRoot1 = "storage";
                }
            }
            if (i == 0) {

                ModelAudioFolder model = new ModelAudioFolder("" + folderId + "/" + folderName, "" + folderName, "", "" + folderId + "/" + folderName, "" + count);
                folderList.add(model);
                Log.d("The_Tag1", "onCreate: " + folderName + " " + folderRoot + " " + folderId + "/" + folderName + " " + count);

            } else if (
                    folderName.equals(new File(audioList.get(i - 1).getDATA()).getParentFile().getName())
                            &&
                            folderRoot.equals(folderRoot1)

            ) {
                //exclude
            } else {
                ModelAudioFolder model = new ModelAudioFolder("" + folderId + "/" + folderName, "" + folderName, "", "" + folderId + "/" + folderName, "" + count);
                folderList.add(model);

                Log.d("The_Tag1", "onCreate: " + folderName + " " + folderRoot + " " + folderId + "/" + folderName + " " + " " + count);

            }

        }


        return folderList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ModelAudioFolder> audioFolderList) {
        super.onPostExecute(audioFolderList);

        Log.d("ModelAudioFolder_Size", "Count:" + audioFolderList.size());

        try {
            if (audioFolderList.size() <= 0) {
                noFoldersRl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                foldersRl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                noFoldersRl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                foldersRl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            Log.d("FoldersSize", "onPostExecute: " + audioFolderList.size());

            adapterAudioFolder = new AdapterAudioFolder(getActivity(), audioFolderList, dashboardActivity);
            foldersRv.setAdapter(adapterAudioFolder);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the exception is `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME`. It is added in API 29. Before this we were using `DISPLAY_NAME` for API 28 & below. Please refer to the docs [BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME).

For solution you can write conditions according to current API level. And for getting folder name, you can use `RELATIVE_PATH`.

Comment: is there any way to get buckets having audio files on below API 29?

Comment: I guess there is no way until they release support sdk for the same

Comment: and 'RELATIVE_PATH' is also added in API 29. I think there's no way then

Answer (score 1):

In API verions <= 28 BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME only exists for images and videos, so, accesible via MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME or  MediaStore.Vidos.VideoColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME.

That said, the solution to get the BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME for **audios** in versions bellow 29, is to parse the **MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA**. This field is deprecated in 29, but still valid in previous versions.

The field contains the actual path + filename, and since a BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME is in reality the actual **parent** folder name where a file is located, what you need to do is to remove the file name, and then get the sub-string starting at the last found backward-slash from the path.